# fileinput not visible while accessing in intranet

Tags: r, rstudio, shinydashboard

I have the below fileinput in my code and it is working fine in my local machine but the same is not visible in the page if i try to access the page in intranet.

```
 fileInput('datafile1', 'Choose the file',
      accept=c('.xlsx',".xls"))
```

Am i missing anything here.